# Arquivos Para Structs/Ponteiros C

Tags: c, arquivo, ponteiro, struct

Tenho esse pequeno programa e estou conseguindo salvar, e carregar do arquivo para struct(não perfeitamente).

O erro é o seguinte: após carregar do arquivo para struct, se na função carregar eu por o printf ele irá printar corretamente todos arquivos da struct que antes se encontravam no arquivo, porem, se eu fizer o mesmo printf em outra função, ou até mesmo tentar salvar no arquivo, ele coloca valores aleatórios na memoria, gostaria de saber onde foi meu erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct produto{
    char nome[40];
    int cod_prod;
    float precoVenda;


};

const CRESCE = 64;
int nroProdutos, capacidadeProds;
struct produto *produto;
int novos_prods;




void CarregarProdutos(){
    FILE *arq = fopen("produtos.txt","r+");
    fscanf(arq,"%d", &nroProdutos);
    capacidadeProds =nroProdutos+CRESCE;
    produto = malloc(capacidadeProds*sizeof(struct produto));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nroProdutos; i++){
        fscanf(arq,"%s", produto[i].nome );
        fscanf(arq,"%d", &(produto[i]).cod_prod );
        fscanf(arq,"%f", &produto[i].precoVenda);
        // se eu aplicar o printf aqui dará tudo certo..
    }



    fclose(arq);
}
void SalvarProdutos(){
    FILE *arq = fopen("produtos.txt","w");
    int i;
    fprintf(arq,"%d\n",novos_prods);
    for (i = 0; i < novos_prods; i++){
        fprintf(arq,"%s\n", produto[i].nome );
        fprintf(arq,"%d\n",  produto[i].cod_prod );
        fprintf(arq,"%f\n", produto[i].precoVenda);
//quando vou salvar pros arquivos os valores saem aleatorios.
//(sei que o erro está na forma que eu leio do arquivo pra memoria)
 }
    fclose(arq);
}
void CadastrarProdutos(){//essa função cadrastra produtos novos a partir 
dos produtos ja existentes, para que não haja sobreposição;
     capacidadeProds =nroProdutos+CRESCE;
    produto = malloc(capacidadeProds*sizeof(struct produto));
    int i = nroProdutos;// essa variavel é a variavel q nao sobrepoe o estoque caso seja diferente de 0
    char x;

    do
    {
        printf("Digite o nome do produto\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", produto[i].nome);
        produto[i].cod_prod = i;
        printf("Digite o preco de compra do produto\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%f", &produto[i].precoVenda);
        printf("deseja cadastrar um novo produto?\n");
        printf("digite n para sair\n");
        printf("digite qualquer tecla para cadastrar novos produtos\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&x);
            i++;
    } while(x != 'n');
        novos_prods = i;
   // chame aqui a proxima funçao, no caso a função menu
   //nesse caso ela esta chamando a função salvar pq aqui esta sem o menu e etc.
   SalvarProdutos();
}

int main()
{
    CarregarProdutos();
    CadastrarProdutos();
}
```

O erro provavelmente esta na forma que é carregada do arquivo para memoria.
agradeceria quem ajudasse, provavelmente na forma em que eu chamo do arquivo para struct, obrigado!

Comment: Como irá funcionar o `CarregarProdutos()` da primeira vez que o programa corre se o arquivo `produtos.txt` não existe ? O `CadastrarProdutos()` também não garante que não cadastra mais registos do que foram alocados no `malloc` pois no `do while` não foi considerado o `i` como ponto de saída também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não tenho compilador de C atualmente, mas pelo que vi o problema estava na forma como estavas a aceder à struct. Quando aparecem variáveis random significa que estavas a aceder a outra coisa que não era a tua struct.

```
void CarregarProdutos(){
FILE *arq = fopen("produtos.txt","r+");
fscanf(arq,"%d", &nroProdutos);
capacidadeProds =nroProdutos+CRESCE;
produto = malloc(capacidadeProds*sizeof(struct produto));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < nroProdutos; i++){
    fscanf(arq,"%s", &(produto+i).nome );
    fscanf(arq,"%d", &(produto+i).cod_prod );
    fscanf(arq,"%f", &(produto+i).precoVenda);
    // se eu aplicar o printf aqui dará tudo certo..
}



fclose(arq);
}
void SalvarProdutos(){
FILE *arq = fopen("produtos.txt","w");
int i;
fprintf(arq,"%d\n",novos_prods);
for (i = 0; i < novos_prods; i++){
    fprintf(arq,"%s\n", &(produto+i).nome );
    fprintf(arq,"%d\n",  &(produto+i).cod_prod );
    fprintf(arq,"%f\n", &(produto+i).precoVenda);
//quando vou salvar pros arquivos os valores saem aleatorios.
(sei que o erro está na forma que eu leio do arquivo pra memoria)
}
fclose(arq);
}
```

Comment: @resolvido!
apenas fiz o que o amigo acima disse e tambem removi essa parte do cadastrarProdutos =
 capacidadeProds =nroProdutos+CRESCE;
    produto = malloc(capacidadeProds*sizeof(struct produto))